# How to get the number of template arguments

Tags: templates, arguments, mediawiki

I am trying to write a template for mediawiki and need to get the number of items passed in.  I could get the user to pass in the number of arguments but that isn't pretty and a pain to use.

My current "solution", make the first argument the number of arguments (which needs to be passed in manually:

```
{{{1}}} arguments passed in.
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution? You mean the user has to pass the number of parameters by hand? Why do you even need the number of arguments?

Comment: Yes, it is the "less then perfect" way that I mentioned earlier in the question.  I made it a little clearer in the question.

Comment: No, that's impossible by default. What extensions do you have installed, ParserFunctions? There might be some (with loops etc) that allow such constructs.

Comment: I don't have control over the server and there are almost no extensions installed.

Comment: @Bergi Assuming that is true it is the answer to my question.  If you put it as an answer I can accept that (assuming no one else comes up with a solution).

Comment: @KevinCox: It might be possible with the right extensions. That's why I asked which one you have installed; are you allowed to install others maybe?

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons (I guess somewhat related to security) MediaWiki gives you no loops, so parameters count is not very useful.  When Wikimedians need a template which accept arbitrary number of arguments, they usually do something like this:

```
<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{4|x}}}|{{{4|}}}| 4 or more | <!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{3|x}}}|{{{3|}}}| 3 | <!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{2|x}}}|{{{2|}}}| 2 | <!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{1|x}}}|{{{1|}}}| 1 | <!--
-->0 }} }} }} }}
```

See example: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Tlp&action=edit

Comment: Probably more DDOS attack related.  Create an infinate loop.

Comment: BTW actually there are loops (or rather something close to) written in MediaWiki's language, see [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Loop) and it's "see also" section. They work in similar way to what I just presented. They heavily rely on template inclusion and, since MediaWiki has some limit on number of inclusions (500 in case of Wikipedias), they are DDOS protected to some point.